# KPL upgrade and batching differences

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I upgraded KPL from version 1.8.10 to 1.14.x and noticed that the data being produced by my Spark job results in smaller Kinesis records (less user records per batch). There is no data quality issue (same amount of user records if you go through all the batches), but my lambda that consumes this data has increased TPS by 20x trying to process these smaller batches and does not scale anymore. Instead of e.g. 1 Kinesis record with 20 user records, my lambda is now processing 20 Kinesis records (1 at a time) with 1 user record each.

I believe the # of Spark tasks and # executors is what impacts the aggregation technique, but I would think that upgrading KPL version wouldn't change the Spark plan in terms of # of tasks/executors. I opened up Spark history server for both runs and they're identical in terms of jobs/stages/executors/tasks - I don't know what the difference is in Spark (if any) that would cause a difference in KPL aggregation.

How do I deduce why KPL is producing different batch sizes and how to configure/change things so they revert back to the same aggregation technique as before the upgrade?